# ASP.NET Core How to make form with few properties each one with own model

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make web application for wedding which allows making reservations for hotels nad buses like on screen shot. 
I don't know how can I save changes in Selects.
I'm using Entity Framework Core. I want to reload page after clicks "accept changes" and edit row in database.

[GuestVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhNtf.png)

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Vlu.png)

Comment: Your question is far too broad. In general, you're going to need to use JavaScript to create sets of repeating fields. This is actually a very difficult thing to achieve, despite sounding so simple, so you'll almost assuredly want to rely on a library like Vue.js, Angular, etc. to handle this logic for you. In short, entire books could and have been written on this topic, so there's no feasible way to help you in a simple answer on Stack Overflow. You'll need to do some research and attempt a solution.

Comment: Thank u Chris. I thought it's easier. I'll try with this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/ Maybe I should start with something simpler.